# TLS Extended Master Secret- calculate session hash

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm  have tool which manually dissect ssl/http traffic using openssl library. It's work fine in most cases, but failed wheen client/server usese Extended Master Secret extension.

Fail  occured on last stage of handshake, where veryfying of test encripted data performed .

As I understand for proper work of this extension I need properly fill handshake buffer with specific TLS fields (client hello, server hello, key exchange) and then master key should be generated baasing on hashing of handshake buffer.

Unfortunatelly it's not work for me.

So my question-which exactly tls packeds should be hashed for generating proper master key ?

Will be gratefull for any comments.
Thanks.

PS: I downloaded experemental version of openssl from github, where this functionality implemented.

openssl s_server/s_client uses corespond extension, Ican see it in Wireshark, and able to decode traffic with server pem file.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: openssl is a programming crypto -framework, and It's was question, about  which function I need to call (and in which order) before calling tls1_generate_master_secret function.
Why this question not about developing ? Thanks.

Comment: The question contains no code references, not even a line from your special tool or OpenSSL. This has nothing to do with programming: ***"... my question-which exactly tls packeds should be hashed for generating proper master key"***. You should take it to a site designed for your question. Or, leave it here and get no answers. Suit yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following to generate the session hash

1) Append all the Handshake messages, other than encrypted handshakes in order of arrival, please don't include the record header to the handshakes. only messages and message headers

2) Hash them based , simple to say, 
   Hash algorithm varies based on Cipher Suite and Protocal Version
   TLS1 and TLS1.1 its mixture of SHA1 and MD5 (16 bit each)
   TLS1.2 its mostly SHA256 or SHA384  based on cipher suite.

Comment: RFC says use HMAC algorithm defined in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2104. What would be the key/seed for this hash? For regular master secret, it's the client-random and server-random concatenated. What would it be for session hash? would client-random and server-random become the seed for session-hash which in turn becomes the seed for EMS?

Comment: I don't remember setting the seed explicitly, 
I used the hash Algorithm from the Cipher suite selected and hashed the session details mentioned above. it worked for me. 
You can refer GNU TLS code, and how they hash the session info. it's much easier to navigate it than OpenSSL.